# How to write script in awk that tells average length of fields in each record, without counting whitespaces?

Tags: linux, awk, files, cygwin

So I need to write an awk script file that finds and prints the average field length of each record in a text document.   The text document is this:

```
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.
The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.
The rain in Spain also falls on the mountains.
```

Right now, what I am using is this, in a script file:

```awk
{average = length($0)/NF
   print "Average field length for record: " average}
```

By doing "length($0)," it counts everything in the record.   I tried doing something like length($1)+length($2)+length($3)+etc., but the records have different lengths and I can't account for that, especially since this is supposed to work with any length record.

The problem that I am having is that it counts whitespaces in between each field, and I don't want to count that.   Currently, the numbers I am getting for each record are 5.2, 4.8, and 5.1, respectively.   Is there a way to not count whitespaces?

In addition to this, I am required to find the average field length in the file as a whole.   Again, I believe my awk script for this one is also counting whitespaces, which I do not want.   This is my script file:

```awk
BEGIN{
        sum = 0
     }
{
     sum += length()
     sum = sum/NF
}
END{
     print "Average field length in file: " sum
     }
```

What modification must I make so that it does not count whitespaces, but only letters and punctuation, basically everything except for the whitespaces?   As is, the number I get for the average of all fields in the text file is 5.7, which I do not believe is correct.

Comment: Are you aware of the `{}` formatting tool to format text as code? It would help in these situations, I'm sure.

Comment: Perhaps pass the input through a `tr` to eliminate whitespace and then run awk over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip whitespace by relying on the default field separator and counting the fields’ sizes, as you suggest, accounting for varying numbers of fields by using the `NF` variable.

Thus for the averages per-record:

```awk
NF > 0 {
    linesum = 0
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) linesum += length($i)
    print "Average field length for record: " linesum / NF
}
```

and for the whole file:

```awk
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) sum += length($i)
    count += NF
}

END { if (count > 0) { print "Average field length in file: " (sum / count) } }
```

This also fixes the problem with calculating averages line by line.

With your example, this gives an average of 4.17857 (counting punctuation).

Comment: Ok, so I ran your script file through awk, and I also get 4.17, but it also prints out these numbers above that, like this: 4.4, 4.1, and 4.3.   How do you get rid of those?   Also, how would I modify that script file to make it work for my first problem of finding the individual record's averages?

Comment: Those extra numbers are the individual records’ averages.

Comment: Ok, but I need to separate those.   They are two different questions, and I am not sure how to separate them apart.   How is it printing those averages if the only thing I see is "print Average field"

Comment: `print linesum / NF` takes care of the individual records. I’ll update my answer to clarify things.

Comment: Ooooh, Okay.   I got it, dude you are a freaking life saver.   You are my favorite person right now.   I actually have another question about the work I have, I will be uploading it soon, and will ask you about it as well, since you're obviously an expert.

Comment: Here is my other post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550529/how-to-add-number-of-fields-throughout-file-together

Comment: I made sure to accept it, and upvote your answer.   I am still trying to figure out how to format my new post correctly though.   I am trying my best.

Comment: Thanks! Take a look at how I edited your question here (click on the “edit” button under the question — you can cancel the edit to avoid making changes).

Comment: Thanks so much for all you've done so far.   I changed my second post, and I think it looks much better now.   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550529/how-to-add-number-of-fields-throughout-file-together